# "That was so that" vs "this is so that"

Tags: grammar

I have a question. correct me If I am wrong: I think when I say

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year. **That *was* so that** I could contact him whenver I wanted to.

it's another way of saying

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year so that I **could** contact him whenever I **wanted** to.

But when I say

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year. **This *is* so that** I can contact him whenever I want to.

it's another way of saying

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year so that I **can** contact him whenever I **want** to.

Am I right?

Comment: Many learners seem to think that such a minor change in the wording somehow drastically alters the meaning of the sentence. It doesn't. These all pretty much convey the same sentiment.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you. But I think If I say "that was so that I can contact him whenever I want to", I will be wrong. Am I right?

Comment: "That was so that ..." and "This was so that ..." sound a little wrong to me. But I'm a learner too. Can someone shed light on this? Thanks!

Comment: @user254288 - You're wrong – the tenses don't need to match. "That **was**...*" is okay because getting him the phone happened in the past; "...whenever I **want**" is okay because the contact is happening in the present and future.

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence reads best, its grammar is easy.

> I gave my dad a mobile phone last year so that I can contact him
>   whenever I want to.

I propose this alternative

> I gave my dad a mobile phone because I want to stay in contact.

Comment: I like "stay in touch" even better than "stay in contact".